# express.js on every page error 500 after adding more routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the latest version of express and used the express generator to create my basic folder and file structure. Now after adding more routes in the `app.js` file I receive on every page an error 500.

Here is the part of my `app.js` where i added the routes:

```js
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var play = require('./routes/play');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var register = require('./routes/register');


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/play', play);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/register', register);
```

My `play.js` file looks like this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { page: 'play' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My `login.js` and `register.js` files look like this(haven't really changed much until now):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { page: 'login' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My folder structure is like this:

```
projectfolder\routes\play.js 
projectfolder\views\index.ejs 
projectfolder\views\modules\Templatefiles.ejs 
projectfolder\app.js
```

What did i wrong?

Comment: can you show your login or register routes? probably you are using `next()` in them?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You should specify more specific routes after more general one.

Reorder your routes like this:

```
app.use('/play', play);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/register', register);
app.use('/', routes);
```

In express, the order of the routes matters. You're getting 500 because the handler for `/` route doesn't have handlers for `play`, `login`, etc paths.

Comment: What is the error that is shown? The same structure works fine in my project.

Comment: Error in the browser is standard 500 page. Console shows this: `GET /favicon.ico 404 2.090 ms - 0
GET /favicon.ico 404 2.615 ms - 0
GET /play 500 13.180 ms - 0
GET /play 500 12.083 ms - 0
GET /play 500 16.320 ms - 0`

Comment: So can you check the network tab and see what the server returns?

Comment: Server returns `document play with status 500`

Comment: Add an error logger to see what the actual error is as it's possibly not due to the routing